# Jquery Media Plugin with alternate mediaplayer problems

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-plugins, swfobject, media-player

I can't seem to get the jQuery Media plugin to work with nonverblaster:hover ...

This is what I'm using....  am I doing something wrong?

I've tried loading SWFobject aswell...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.fn.media.defaults.flvPlayer = 'js/NonverBlaster.swf';
    $.fn.media.defaults.mp3Player = 'js/NonverBlaster.swf';

    /* Audio  */
    $.fn.media.mapFormat('mp3','flash');
    $.fn.media.mapFormat('aac','flash');

    /* Video */
    $.fn.media.mapFormat('mov','flash');
    $.fn.media.mapFormat('mp4','flash');
    $.fn.media.mapFormat('m4v','flash');

    $('a.media').media();
});
</script>
```

[NonverBlaster:hover](http://nonverbla.de/blog/2008/09/15/nonverblasterhover/comment-page-5/)

[jQuery Media Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/media/)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the "player" page ;-)

The jQuery Media Plug-In likes the JW Media Player. Change this player and use the correct values. ;-)